# Метод filter для массива - непонятное условие

Tags: javascript, массивы, filter

Есть задачка. Удалить все элементы из массива (arguments[0]), которые содержат значения из arguments[1], [2]..

Т.е `destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3)` должен удалять 2 и 3 из массива, и возвращать [1, 1]

А `destroyer([3, 5, 1, 2, 2], 2, 3, 5)` должен вернуть [1].

Я решил с помощью цикла, но нагуглил другой способ это сделать.

```
function destroyer(arr) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); // делаем массив
    args.splice(0,1); // удаляем первый элемент
    return arr.filter(function(element) {
        return args.indexOf(element) === -1; // ВОТ ЭТО СРАВНЕНИЕ НЕПОНЯТНО.
    });
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Я не врубаюсь что это значит

```
args.indexOf(element) === -1;
```

indexOf возвращает номер элемента массива, а не его значение.

Answer (score 1):

`.indexOf()` возвращает `-1`, если этого элемента в искомом массиве **нет**. Иначе он вернет индекс этого элемента.